# Calculating a 3 Circle Venn Diagram only knowing A, B, and C?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

I came across this question:

> If there are 40 students in a class, 30 of them got A in Music, 33 of them got A in PE, and 37 of them got A in Art, at least how many students got all 3 As?

The first thing that came to my mind is to use Venn Diagram to solve it.

But most of the time when we solve Venn Diagram problems, $A \cap B, A \cap C, B \cap C$, and $A \cap B \cap C$ are provided, namely, calculate the "total" amount of students in the class (40 in this case).

But this kind of problem must be able to be "reverse engineered" just like any other math problem.

So I went on and set

$A=30, B=33, C=37$

$A+B+C-A \cap B-A \cap C-B \cap C + A \cap B \cap C =40$ (Assuming that nobody got no As)

So,

$\overline{A}=(B-A \cap B) + (C-A \cap C) - B \cap C=10$

$\overline{B}=(A-A \cap B) + (C-B \cap C) - A \cap C=7$

$\overline{C}=(B-B \cap C) + (A-A \cap C) - A \cap B=3$

And if I sum this up and add another $A+B+C$, then it's $3(A+B+C-A \cap B-A \cap C-B \cap C)$, then I could calculate $A \cap B \cap C$ from it.

But unfortunately, $3(A+B+C-A \cap B-A \cap C-B \cap C)$ turned out to be exactly 120, so $A+B+C-A \cap B-A \cap C-B \cap C=40$ and $A \cap B \cap C$ is $0$!

So then I thought, maybe I shouldn't assume that nobody got no As.

And set a $\alpha$ as the number of students that got no As.

But soon find out this number will be "canceled" in the operation and therefore completely useless whatsoever!

Could somebody please be so kind and tell me where did I do wrong?

Much appreciated!

**Update:**

When I keep pondering through the problem, I first thought it might be the case just like the image below:

[image]

Where there "not necessary" have to have $A \cap B \cap C$.

But when I double-check it by changing all 3 circles to 40 (meaning everybody got all straight As, thus $A \cap B \cap C$ should be 40 as well) and run through it with my calculation, I found out that $A \cap B \cap C$ is "still 0"!

Which means this way of calculation is "completely wrong"!

So I thought, maybe I could set it up like

[image]

and solving for `g`.

Then

$a+b+f+g=30$

$b+c+d+g=33$

$d+e+f+g=37$

$a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h=40$

And found out that this linear equation simply "does not have enough information" to go on.

Could somebody please be so kind and teach me the correct way of doing it?

Much appreciated!

**PS.**

I found out why it's always 0:

Because those 3 equations I add up are originally $\overline{A}, \overline{B},$ and $\overline{C}$, and if I add another $A+B+C$ to it, I'm essentially adding $A+\overline{A}+B+\overline{B}+C+\overline{C}$, so ***of course*** it will be $3U (120)$ "no matter what"!

But, I still don't undertand why my "logic" is wrong, according to the equations, it "should" leave $A \cap B \cap C$, but how come it somehow "disappeared" in the process? I really don't understand.

Comment: Notice that it asks ‘*at least* how many got A’s in all 3 subjects?”

Comment: @Bram28 Please be so kind and take a look at my update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earlier I provided an "answer" as a hint (in the form of a question). It was deleted as being more appropriate as a comment ("request for clarification") it was not a request for clarification. It was a hint in the form of a question.

"Hint: How many total A's were there out of how many total grades?"

The point is that there were $30+33+37=100$ total A's out of $3\cdot 40=120$ total grades. Hence there were $20$ grades that were not A's. If these grades were maximally spread around among the $40$ students, there would have been $20$ students who got a non A. (There may have been less such students, as some students could have gotten more than one non A.) But in any case that would mean that there are least $40-20=20$ students who got all A's.

Comment: Wow! This is much easier to understand! I guess I went on the wrong direction "from the very beginning" because it was so similar to Venn Diagram problems and got mislead by it! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This is more like an "IQ test" than a regular question! ToT

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = |A\cap B\cap C|$ be the number of students that got all As.

We use the inclusion-exclusion formula,

$$ |A| + |B| + |C| - |A\cap B| - |B\cap C|-|C\cap A| + |A\cap B\cap C| = |A\cup B\cup C|,$$

to get

$$x = |A\cup B\cup C| - |A| - |B| - |C| + |A\cap B| + |B\cap C|+|C\cap A|$$

To find a bound, we need to bound the intersections: using $$|A\cup B \cup C| \geq |A\cup B| = |A|+|B| - |A\cap B|,$$ we can rearrange to obtain $$|A\cap B| \geq |A| + |B| - |A\cup B \cup C|.$$ Plugging that (and analogous expressions) back into the equality for $x$ gives

$$x \geq |A\cup B \cup C|  - |A|-|B|-|C|\\+ (|A|+|B|-|A\cup B \cup C| ) \\+ (|B|+|C|-|A\cup B \cup C| ) \\+ (|C|+|A|-|A\cup B \cup C| ) \\= |A|+|B|+|C| - 2|A\cup B\cup C|.$$

Thus $x \geq |A|+|B|+|C| - 2\cdot40 = 20$, because $40 \geq |A\cup B\cup C|$.

Comment: Okay I might be wrong but I am fairly certain that while this bound is correct it is not tight. I think the correct lower bound is 20. You can see this by first noting that 30 people are in A. Then by assigning as many from B to not be in a we see that the intersection of A and B has at least 23, then applying the same logic with C we get 20. I cannot see any way to only have 17.

Comment: @Mentastin  I think also that 20 is a tight bound. To show that 17 is a tight bound you should show us sets A,B,C where x=17.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. 20 is the tight bound (the discrepancy is due to first bounding by 37 and then by 40). I will edit.

Comment: @Mentastin Please rework your proof. But I can't see how you can claim that $|A\cup B\cup C| = 40$

Comment: I don't, I claim that $|A\cup B\cup C| \leq 40$. So $x \geq |A|+|B|+|C|-2|A\cup B\cup C| \geq |A|+|B|+|C| -2*40 = 20$.

Comment: @Mentastin I have to said that I'm sorry that I don't understand how you obtain that. I managed to undertand the proof "before" the last edit, but failed at the last one. Please be so kind and elaborate "a little more", much appreciated.

Comment: @Mentastin OK, first, thanks, second, so basically you're replacing 37 in the original proof with 40 (unbounded). But I still think the original bound should be the correct one, because what the "minimum" of the union of all 3 circles ***is*** 37 (when all 3 circles overlapping each other, even though that will leave $A \cap B \cap C$ to be 30, I don't know if that's the reason why this could not be the lower bound of the unions).

Comment: The original bound is correct, but not, as was pointed out, optimal. The new bound is better (and in fact optimal you can easily see this by constructing an example (hint we have always set $A\cup B = A\cup B\cup C$, what does this say about $C\setminus (A\cup B)$?))

Comment: Notice that the smaller the total number of students, the more restrictive the bound. The intuition here is the following: *with enough total students* we can take the sets $A,B$ and $C$ to be disjoint, in which case the intersection is zero. With fewer total students we need to put some in the intersection in order to get our quotas for all sets.

Comment: @Mentastin I'm sorry that I'm confused. If the lesser answer could be obtained, shouldn't that be the "optimal" answer since the "least" amount of straight A students is asked?

Comment: @noob002 17 cannot be obtained but it is a lower bound. As a more extreme example -1 is clearly a lower bound on the size of the intersection, but it is clearly not obtainable. The point is that while 17 is a lower bound it doesn't answer the question as it can never be obtained.

Comment: @Mentastin I changed the best answer to paw88789's because it's much easier to understand, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Adding to that, this is generally why I would recommend against non constructive proofs for these sorts of questions. (i.e. ones where we are dealing with small sets and we want exact answers) Non constructive proofs will often give non-tight bounds which are fine if it is in service of answering something else or the question doesn't need an exact answer but can be problematic otherwise as shown here.

Comment: @Fishbane I'm sorry, are you trying to say that proofs like Mentastin's is better even though it's much harder to understand? Or simply just saying that I asked a bad question? ToT

Comment: @Noob002 Actually exactly the opposite. I think that Mentastin's proof while accurate trys too hard to use 'fancy' maths when simpler proofs like paw88789's are easier to understand and give better results. I'm mostly trying to be diplomatic because Mentastin's proof is correct and might be useful if we were working in a more complicated situation but honestly here it is just kind of messy. My point was that 'constructive' proofs like paw88789's are better in these situations. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Adding to that, the point of maths is broadly to explain things, so if a proof leaves you confused it is probably a bad proof. (Excluding possibly things at a much higher level although I would still argue a proof shouldn't leave you confused.)

Comment: @Fishbane Oh, OK, thanks for the clarification. ^o^